# Suppose $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, what does it mean to write $H \leq K \leq G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, notation

I am following J.B. Fraleigh: A first course in abstract algebra. In the text page $101$ the author supposes $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ then uses the notation $H \leq K \leq G$. Does he intend to write, $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$, $|H| \leq |K| \leq |G|$, or something different? I cannot recall that such notation for sets has been defined in my prior maths courses.

Comment: I think it's subgroup notation.

Comment: What's that? I cannot recall the definition of subgroup notation.

Comment: This is pretty nonstandard notation, but the assumptions about what it means by others in here seem pretty reasonable. I suspect that this is not used much because it is a bit close to normal subgroup notation.

Comment: I've seen that notation used as subgroup notation. Groups and symmetry by Armstrong uses that notation.

Comment: For those of us who grew up on Herstein's Algebra, it is THE standard notation.

Comment: It means $H$ is a subgroup of K, and K \subgroup of G (and also H is a subgroup G).

Comment: Does there exist more standard notation?

Comment: @MariusJonsson: I would say no. Others will say yes. To answer this question I think you need to survey the standard textbooks in abstract algebra. This should give you an idea about what is most common. You could also try to search research articles on group theory and see what notation they tend to use. At the end of the day as you progress in mathematics you need to get comfortable with people using different notation (and even different definitions at times!).

Comment: I disagree with @Cameron, in my experience it is very common, even standard, to write $H\le G$ to say $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the other answer makes clear people will prefer different things. But it is completely standard to write
$$
H\leq G
$$
when we want to say that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. So saying that 
$$
H\leq K\leq G
$$
says that $H$ is a subgroup of $K$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. (As a side note, $\leq$ is a transitive, so this would also mean that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.)

I looked in a couple of my abstract algebra books, and the following books use $\leq$ for subgroups

- Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra book*
- Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*
- Rotman's *Advanced Modern Algebra*
- Herstein's *Topics in Aglebra*
- Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*

Even [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) on subgroups uses the notation. Hungerford uses $<$.

One advantage of using $\leq$ over $\subseteq$ is that it distinguishes between being a subset and a subgroup. In a proof you might first show that $H$ is a subset of $G$ and then later conclude that $H$ is a subgroup. So having different notations can be helpful.

Comment: It is also worth noting that $\leq$ is a natural notation since it is a partial ordering on the subgroup lattice of the group.

Answer (score 4):

I would say this $$H \subseteq K \subseteq G$$ and that $H$ is a subgroup of $K$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: It takes more than being a subset of a set to make it a subgroup of a group.

Comment: True, so I write that $H$ is also a subgroup of $K$ ...